# Configure JDBC Data Source for use with JNDI and Tomcat 6 in JSF 2 project

Tags: java, jsf-2, jdbc, tomcat6, jndi

I'm working on a web app using JSF 2 that will be deployed in Tomcat 6. I need to access an HSQLDB data source using JNDI. I cannot modify the `server.xml` file for Tomcat, nor any other "Tomcat files". I've seen various tutorials and explanations about this, but all include steps about modifying `server.xml`, etc., which is not permitted in this case. My question is, can this be done without modifying the Tomcat files (i.e. only making changes to files within `META-INF` and `WEB-INF`, like `web.xml`, and other files to be deployed in the .war file? If so, which files need to be modified and how? This is the first time I'm setting up access to a DB via JNDI, the more detailed the response, the better. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Apache Tomcat JNDI How-To](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html)

There you can read that you just need to modify/create projects `context.xml` in META-INF and `web.xml` in WEB-INF ...

> Configure the JNDI DataSource in Tomcat by adding a declaration for
>   your resource to your Context.
>
> ```
>   <Resource name="jdbc/TestDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
>                maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
>                username="javauser" password="javadude" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
>                url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javatest"/>
> ```
>
> Now create a WEB-INF/web.xml for this test application.
>
> ```
>   <resource-ref>
>       <description>DB Connection</description>
>       <res-ref-name>jdbc/TestDB</res-ref-name>
>       <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
>       <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
>   </resource-ref>
> ```

Comment: I'd suggest you to read [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer), in particular: **Provide context for links:** _A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there . Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline._

Comment: @BackSlash I hope it now meets the requirements!?

Comment: This helps. I've added the necessary files/code to my project, and have (possibly) had success. I still need to do more testing. However, I had a follow-up question. I used the code as you posted, with changes to make it appropriate for HSQLDB. When I tried to get a conn via `Context initialContext = new InitialContext();` then `DataSource ds = (DataSource)initialContext.lookup("jdbc/TestDB");` I got a NamingException telling me that the name wasn't found. But when I do `.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/TestDB")` at first glance, it appears it finds the name. Why?

Comment: as described in the apache howto: "When accessing the datasource programmatically, remember to prepend java:/comp/env to your JNDI lookup". If you want to know why, I suggest that you read the howto further and the page about the Context container.

Comment: I must have missed that part. I'll take another look. Thanks for the link and the answer.